# Gatling maven project downloads dependencies but cannot find them

Tags: java, maven, gatling

Got a weird issue with a Gattling project (https://github.com/jecklgamis/gatling-java-example) , even if maven is able to download the dependency, when I go to a java class and try to import and use it, it doesn't appear.
Tried to add testng and lombok, but when trying **import lombok.** or **import org.testng.** is not working.

My pom file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jecklgamis</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-java-example</artifactId>
    <name>gatling-java-example</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
<!--        <testResources>-->
<!--            <testResource>-->
<!--                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>-->
<!--                <includes>-->
<!--                    <include>**/*.xml</include>-->
<!--                    <include>**/*.conf</include>-->
<!--                </includes>-->
<!--            </testResource>-->
<!--        </testResources>-->
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.10.1</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <target>1.8</target>-->
<!--                    <source>1.8</source>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.4.1</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>-->
<!--                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>-->
<!--                    <filters>-->
<!--                        <filter>-->
<!--                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>-->
<!--                            <excludes>-->
<!--                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>-->
<!--                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>-->
<!--                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>-->
<!--                            </excludes>-->
<!--                        </filter>-->
<!--                    </filters>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <phase>package</phase>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>shade</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/main/java</simulationsFolder>
                    <runMultipleSimulations>false</runMultipleSimulations>
                    <simulationClass>gatling.simulation.SormasSimulation</simulationClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: In what IDE? Is it a Maven project (in the IDE)? There's no generic answer since it depends on the IDE and/or your Maven setup etc.

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo-java

Comment: tried, but is the same, downloading dependencies but not able to import them in classes

Comment: Are you really sure you're importing the project in your IDE as a maven project?

Comment: POM file was opened as project, yes.
Managed to fix it, the problem was that the project was directly opened within my main team's project, as a new module, and the was a script blocking downloading dependencies already defined in main POM file, to avoid code duplication.